# Vaadin 19/20 + official gradle plugin - custom servlet subpath to run within existing legacy web application along another Java framework

Tags: java, gradle, vaadin

**Environment**

Spring 4.3 (no Spring Boot!), JDK 8/11, Tomcat 8.5.x, Vaadin 19/20-SNAPSHOT

I have a legacy webapp running another servlet-api-driven web framework at http://app.com. I want to add a path that adds a Vaadin-driven UI to this application - let's say at http://app.com/vaaadin-app . I'm using the newly developed official Gradle plugin. (Both Vaadin and non-Vaadin web applications should be run from single WAR, effectively sharing single classloader for shared state access, so no proxy/rewrite/etc solutions will help here).

**Problem**

After adding dependencies the Vaadin app is properly built and war created. Yet as soon as I call http://app.com (not http://app.com/vaadin-app) it looks like Vaadin servlet/whatever is taking over all requests. It looks like it is automatically initialized by (I guess) servlet 3.0 annotations.

**Question**
How can I enable Vaadin only for http://app.com/vaadin-app and keep it away from altering requests not directed there? I know with Vaadin 8 it was possible to achieve this with:

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>vaadinServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>UI</param-name>
            <param-value>app.vaadin.additem.AddItemUI</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>vaadinServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/vaadin-app/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>vaadinServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/VAADIN/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

In other words: how to prevent Vaadin 19/20 from spawning itself automatically for /* but to serve application only when user hits the /vaadin-app/* servlet path???
I think in case of maven plugin there was the "disable.automatic.servlet.registration" option to achieve this? But I don't see anything like this in case of Gradle plugin.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The servlet registration in Vaadin should have nothing related to Gradle, so applying the generic instructions should work. The automatic servlet registration is omitted if you define a VaadinServlet manually (extend it and map the servlet to your location of choice using @WebServlet).

Check this part of the documentation for more details: https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/flow/advanced/application-lifecycle/#automatic-servlet-registration